# Where is my Proofreader badge?

Tags: support, badges

For Proofreader badge badge we need to

> Approved or rejected 100 suggested edits

So why didn't I got it.  As per the [stats](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats), I have completed 101 Suggested Edits. There are only four users on our site who have completed 100 suggested edit approvals:  iandotkelly, TylerShads, wbogacz, and me. But I am the only one who hasn't received the badge yet.

Is there something that I am missing?  Why don't I have the badge yet?

Comment: Did you complete the 100th review recently, like today?  If so, some badges are not awarded immediately, but the code which awards them runs less frequently.

Comment: @iandotkelly nopes, i have completed 100 on Mar 30th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are in the same situation as [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173439/where-is-my-proofreader-badge).

Suggested edit audits appear to be part of the SE system - automated bogus edits designed to be rejected.  See:

[Are the suggested edit audits too easy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171204/are-the-suggested-edit-audits-too-easy)

Before I looked into your issue, I had no idea these suggested edit audits took place.

Suggested audit reviews are counted on the stats, but for some unknown reason don't count towards the badge.  You are probably close to gaining the badge though